# Json to Array to extract value PHP

Tags: php, json

I have one Json file and i need to extract the "tempm" I have try using different forms but couldn't never get only that value.
[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkk9F.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkk9F.png)

```
$history1 = ("http://link_to_my_api");
echo $history1;
$json_string = file_get_contents($history1);
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
$location = $parsed_json->{'history'}->{'observations'};

var_dump( $location[0]);
```

Comment: I think it would be better to convert it to an array rather than object. Add true as the second parameter of json_decode, it makes it easier to navigate.

Comment: thats it :D thank you

Comment: I posted it as an answer, mark it as accepted to close the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the json output to an array rather than an object by adding true as the second parameter of json_encode, makes everything easier to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

untested, but i guess this should work:

```
function ext($obj,$name){
    $ret=array();
    $rem=array();
    $f=function() use(&$rem,&$ret,$name){
        $v=reset($rem);
        assert(NULL!==($key1=key($rem)));
        unset($rem[$key1]);
        foreach($v as $key2=>$value){
            if($key2==$name){$ret[]=$value;}
            if(is_array($value) || is_object($value))
            {
                $rem[]=$value;
            }
        }
    };
    $rem[]=$obj;
    while(!empty($rem))
    {
        $f();
    }       
    return $ret;
}

$tempm_arr=ext($parsed_json,'tempm');
$tempm=$tempm_arr[0];
```

warning: this could cause an infinite loop on objects/arrays with recursive references..